# Как происходит компиляция приложений на Android?

Tags: android

Может кто-нибудь рассказать поэтапно как скомпилировать какой-нибудь код (например на C++) на Андроиде? Я в этом без понятия, но знаю что это достаточно сложно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваш код написан к примеру на `Java` (Это более частый случай). Каждое `Android`-приложение состоит из компонентов. Компоненты реализованы в виде Java-классов.

Например, `Activity` в `Android` представляет экран или часть экрана устройства пользователя. Это экземпляр класса `Java` с именем `Android.app.Activity`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другим примером является элемент пользовательского интерфейса `Button`. Кнопка в приложении `Android` - это экземпляр класса `Java` с именем `Android.widget.Button`.

**1. Компиляторы Android (DALVIK vs ART)**

Ваш исходный код компилируется стандартным компилятором Java. После он становится байт-кодом (с расширением «.class»). Этот код идет на второй раунд компиляции (опять-таки к байт-коду - но на этот раз он свернут). Байт-код исполняется с помощью JVM для конкретных целей (виртуальная машина Java), которая является средой выполнения для Java. Но для Android у нас есть две разные виртуальные машины:

- DALVIK
- ART

***DALVIK***

До ART (который был представлен с выпуском Android 4.4, то есть Kitkat), средой выполнения для приложений Android была DALVIK. У DALVIK был один существенный недостаток - это было МЕДЛЕННО!

Пользователям было неприятно использовать свои приложения на своих устройствах, поскольку приложения зависали во время работы.

Dalvik использует модель компиляции JIT. JIT-компилятор компилирует приложение, когда они открываются пользователями (процедура запуска приложения). Таким образом, это замедляло открытие приложений и, в свою очередь, затрудняло работу пользователя.

***ART***

ART использует опережающую модель компиляции, которая компилирует приложения в машинный код после установки

Приложения работают немного быстрее! в рамках ART время запуска приложений сокращается.

Он также улучшил сборку мусора, так что пользователь видит меньше пауз и заиканий в среде с низким объемом памяти. АРТ имеет свои ограничения:

- Проблема со временем установки: Процесс установки медленный с ART, поскольку преобразование приложений в машинный код занимает много времени.
- Проблема размера: компиляция кода после установки означает, что приложение должно «жить» на вашем устройстве. Таким образом, для относительно меньшего Java-кода машина или байт-код будут сравнительно большими.

Вот [тут](https://www.quora.com/From-what-Ive-read-online-it-seems-like-Google-is-planning-to-default-to-ART-in-a-future-release-Why-is-ART-better-than-Dalvik) обсуждают что лучше Dalvik или ART.

**2. Процесс компиляции Android**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.1. Из исходного кода в байт-код

Вам понадобится `JDK (Java Developer Kit)` для компиляции кода `Java` вашего приложения.

Ваш код и предварительно скомпилированные классы из среды выполнения и пользовательских библиотек сначала компилируются `Javac (JIT Compiler / Standard Java Compiler)`.

`Javac` выводит набор файлов байт-кода Java. Пока это выглядит как любой процесс компиляции `Java`, но следующий шаг компиляции делает процесс компиляции уникальным для `Android`.

2.2. Обфускатор (ProGuard инструмент)

Этот шаг не является обязательным, вы можете пропустить этот шаг, если хотите.

Инструмент `ProGuard` берет файлы байт-кода `Java` (выводится как шаг № 1) и отправляет их через инструмент с именем ProGuard. Это сведет к минимуму и запутает (то есть - сделает неясным, неясным или неразборчивым) ваш код.

По умолчанию он отключен в новых проектах `Android`, но когда `ProGuard` включен, он анализирует ваш код и удаляет реализации методов, например, которые не вызываются.

Это может значительно сократить ваш пакет распространяемого приложений. Он также запутывает ваш код, изменяя имена методов и так усложняя декомпиляцию упакованного Java-кода третьим лицом или организацией.

Независимо от использования `ProGuard` вы снова получите файлы `.class` (минимизированный байт-код).

2.3. От минимизированного байт-кода до кода `dex`

Следующим шагом является получение выходных файлов из шага № 2 и преобразование этих файлов в байт-код `dex` - `Dalvik EXecutable (.DEX)`.

Байт-код `DEX` - это формат, оптимизированный для `Android`, который может быть выполнен в более старой среде выполнения `DALVIK` или более новой среде выполнения `ART`.

2.4. Исполнение машинного кода

Во время выполнения устройства считывают эти файлы dex (вывод шага № 3) и перекомпилируют некоторые файлы в машинный код для максимально быстрого выполнения.

В DALVIK этот шаг происходит, когда приложение работает с использованием архитектуры `Just-In-Time` или `JIT`.

В более новой версии `ART` перекомпиляция (или перевод в машинный код) происходит при первой установке приложения, что означает, что приложение может работать быстрее, когда пользователь запускает его на своем устройстве.

И вот как ваш код `Java` превращается во что-то, что работает на `Android`. Он начинается с `Java` и через пару шагов превращается в то, что может прочитать и выполнить среда выполнения `Android`.

Вот еще есть иллюстрация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылки после исследования вопроса. Некоторые были использованы для построения этого вопроса: [ссылка_1](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run) и [ссылка_2](https://medium.com/android-stars/how-android-code-i%CC%87s-compiled-5557cf82ebe9). А [вот](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-compilation-process) и первоисточник этого ответа. Данная информация находится в полностью свободном доступе :) Надеюсь вам стало немного понятнее как именно компилируются приложения.

Comment: То есть мне нужно C++ код компилировать прямо непосредственно Java компилятором, как написано на схеме выше или как?

Comment: c++ можно использовать в android studio, поддержка есть

Comment: С++ в Android Studio только для нативных библиотек) На нем нельзя писать проги)